# property value as another property value from the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, copy

here is my code:

```js
let font = {
  info: {
    height: 5,
    width: 5,
    margin: 1,
  },
  A: [" ### ", "#   #", "#####", "#   #", "#   #"],
  a: [" ### ", "#   #", "#####", "#   #", "#   #"],
  B: ["#### ", "#   #", "#### ", "#   #", "#### "],
  b: ["#### ", "#   #", "#### ", "#   #", "#### "],
  C: [" ####", "#    ", "#    ", "#    ", " ####"],
  c: [" ####", "#    ", "#    ", "#    ", " ####"],
};
```

I want to set the value of `a` to `A`, how do I do that?
I've tried `a: this.A`, `a: font.A` and `a: ( function(){ return this.A } )()`, but no one worked

Comment: Can you put an attempt to the code too, so we can see where exactly you want to change the value.

Comment: in your example they already have the exact same value

Comment: they have but if I edited `A` then `a` won't be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const font = {
  info: {
    height: 5,
    width: 5,
    margin: 1,
  },
  A: [" ### ", "#   #", "#####", "#   #", "#   #"],
  get a() { return this.A; },
  B: ["#### ", "#   #", "#### ", "#   #", "#### "],
  b: ["#### ", "#   #", "#### ", "#   #", "#### "],
  C: [" ####", "#    ", "#    ", "#    ", " ####"],
  c: [" ####", "#    ", "#    ", "#    ", " ####"],
};

console.log(font.a);
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates. You have answered a similar question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68145023'

Comment: is it possible to use arrow functions?

Comment: @Khalidshammout you can't use arrow functions: [ES6 getter/setter with arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827519)